# OutOfMemoryException adding many image frames to Image List

Tags: c#, image, out-of-memory

When attempting to add image frames using SelectActiveFrame to an image list I get an Out of Memory exception. All works 100% if I process less than 174 pages but anything over this produces this error. In it's simplest form my code is;

```
var scannedImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\rbl\Documents\Modelware\City Prop\TIFF Files\barcodememory.tiff");
var dim = new FrameDimension(scannedImage.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
var imageCount = scannedImage.GetFrameCount(dim);
var currentBatch = new List<Image>();

for (var i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
{
scannedImage.SelectActiveFrame(dim, i);

currentBatch.Add(new Bitmap(scannedImage));
// Above experiences following error after +/- 174 pages
//System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
//Message=Out of memory.
//Source=System.Drawing
}
```

Comment: To verify if it's a memory problem, just get the dim and create 200 empty Bitmaps of that size. And for clarity, use a little less `var`.

Comment: Don't believe this to be memory as physical memory running at 65%. Re my use of vars, they were recommended by ReSharper so interesting to hear that this is not good practice. Thanks. I actually suspected this is not good

Comment: Don't look at TaskMan, run some code. OOM can be caused by fragmentation of the LOH.

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of memory. You need to load the images in batches (just load what you need and unload it as you no longer need it.)

Anyways... I don't see why you need several bitmaps. Just do `new Bitmap(...)` once and reuse it (unless the code you pasted is actually not your real code and you're processing several `scannedImage` inside that for loop.)

Comment: Thanks. I have monitored my memory but see no indication that this is running out. Physical memory running at 65%. In regard to doing "new Bitmap(scannedImage)" once and then re-using the same image - I believe my code is correct as I am not using the same image each time. I am working with a multi-page TIFF file using a new frame (SelectActiveFrame) of the 174 page image each time.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that I am able to resolve my problem by converting the frame to a bytestream and then back to an image. The following works 100% (just not sure why, or whether this is a good solution).

```
for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
{
    image.SelectActiveFrame(dim, i);
    var byteStream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    frames[i] = Image.FromStream(byteStream);
}
```